# printing weird symbols to output file, c++

Tags: c++, symbols, into-outfile

I am writing a code that reads an input file of numbers, sorts them in ascending order, and prints them to output. The only thing printed to output is some really freaky symbols.

Here is my code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, y, temp, num[20];
    char file_nameI[21], file_nameO[21];
    ofstream outfile;
    ifstream infile;

    cout << "Please enter name of input file:  ";
    cin >> file_nameI;
    infile.open(file_nameI);
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file \n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter name of output file:  ";
    cin >> file_nameO;
    outfile.open(file_nameO);
    if (!outfile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open output file \n";
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        y = i + 1;
        while (y < 5)
        {
            if (num[i] > num[y])      //Correction3
            {
                infile >> temp;
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[y];
                num[y] = temp;
                //y++;          //Correction4
            }
            y++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        outfile << "num[i]:" << num[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my input

```
6 7 9 0 40
```

Here is the output

```
 „Ô,üþ 54
H|À°ÀzY „Ô,üþ 0
```

Comment: Use debugger. What are the elements of `num` when you enter your loop?

Comment: The output should contain "num[i]" somewhere, at least. The fact that you claim it's not indicates that either this is not the actual code you're working with, or you're looking at the wrong file, according to Occam's Razor. Furthermore, since the shown code is obviously using uninitialized variables, this is already undefined behavior, and all bets are off. Learn how to use a debugger, and step through your code, one line at a time, examining the values of all variables.

Comment: You really should split the sorting and file operations.  Read the file into the array, sort the array, and then output it.  That makes this a lot easier problem.

Comment: Start with a program that reads an array and then prints it back. When you get it right, add sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems with your code are already mentioned in the comments but again:

1. First problem is uninitialized elements of `num[20]` - elements of `num` have *indeterminate values* so accessing any of them triggers undefined behavior. You should first read them from the file or at least initialize them to some default value.
2. The part of code that should most likely do the sorting is just completely wrong. If you'd like to implement your own function for sorting, you can pick up some well-known algorithm like e.g. [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) - but C++ Standard Library already provides sorting function - `std::sort`.

Besides obvious mistakes:

1. You are using `char[]` - in C++ it's almost always better to use `std::string`.
2. Your static array can only store 20 values and you are reading those from a file. You can use `std::vector` which can grow when you add more elements than its current capacity. It also automatically fixes the problem with uninitialized elements of `num[20]`.
3. As mentioned in the comments you can organize your code and improve readability by splitting it into functions.

Here you've got it quickly rewritten. This code uses `std::string` instead of `char[]`, `std::vector` to store the numbers and `std::sort`. If there is something you don't understand here, read SO documentation:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> read_file(ifstream& in_file)
{
    vector<int> vec;
    int value;
    while (in_file >> value)
    {
        vec.push_back(value);
    }

    return vec;
}

void write_file(ofstream& out_file, const vector<int>& values)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        out_file << "value #" << i << ": " << values[i] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    string input_filename, output_filename;
    ofstream out_file;
    ifstream in_file;

    cout << "Please enter name of input file: ";
    cin >> input_filename;
    in_file.open(input_filename);
    if (!in_file)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter name of output file: ";
    cin >> output_filename;
    out_file.open(output_filename);
    if (!out_file)
    {
        cout << "Could not open output file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    auto numbers = read_file(in_file);

    sort(begin(numbers), end(numbers));

    write_file(out_file, numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice program, but it doesn't exactly show what's wrong with OP's code.

Comment: @mpiatek gee I hope one day I can code as well as you do. Thanks for the advice! I am doing this as a class assignment, so unfortunately, I cannot use most of the cool suggestions you had because either my professor wants us to do it the unnecessarily long and complicated way, or the compiler he requires us to use doesn't recognize the new and fancy code.

Comment: @Morgan Welcome to the site. I'd like to remark that 1) If your professor disapproves using `string`, `vector` and `sort()` in a **C++** program (notice: not *C*), I think you have a horrible professor and should probably run away; 2) These are supported if you are using any *C++* compiler (again, not *C*!) from the last 15 years or so; and 3) If you deem this answer to be the optimal solution to the problem you presented in the question, you should accept it. Whether you can or cannot actually resort to it because of reasons not present in the original question should be addressed...

Comment: ... in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You might forgot to store values in `num` array. Just update your code as follows and it will work.

```
infile.open(file_nameI);
if (!infile){
    cout << "Could not open input file \n";
    return 0;
} else{
    i = 0;
    while (infile >> num[i]){
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Morgan if my answer helped you, you can accept it.